# Angular Scope object not retaining the values and returning null in HTML

Tags: angularjs

I have a simple angular function where I call a service to get data and store it a Angular scope as JS array. The issue is the array in the scope object is not visible in my HTML. One thing here is I redirect my view to another HTML, I am not sure if that is a reason.

```
cart.items(localStorage.getItem('userEmail')).then(function(response){
    $.each(response.data, function(index, element) {
               $scope.vendorCartList.push(element);
    });
    $location.path('/vendorHome');                                  
})
```

When I dump this scope array $scope.vendorCartList in the debug console, it displays the content properly.
In my HTML vendorHome.html, I am trying to retrieve the list through ng-repeat and it never works. I tried to dump the scope object, its printing null, not sure what am I missing here

```
<div>
  {{vendorCartList}}
</div>
<div ng-repeat="elements in vendorCartList">
  {{elements}} 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The redirect is exactly the reason. try commenting it out. The service is being called in one scope, and when you redirect using `$location.path('someUrl')`, the scope changes. Hence, the issue.

If the cart items are required in the `vendorHome` page, inject the service there, and call the function inside `vendorHome's` controller.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. I injected the service in vendorController and called the function, then I was able to fetch this list in HTML

Comment: I am glad I could be of help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, Where there is nothing role of index.

```
cart.items(localStorage.getItem('userEmail')).then(function(response){
    $.each(response.data, function(element) {
               $scope.vendorCartList.push(element);
    });
    $location.path('/vendorHome');                                  
})
```

Comment: I tried but no difference. FYI, With my earlier code when I dump it in the console, it displays the content but not visible in HTML

Comment: Are you initializing scope variable when page loads after routing ?

Comment: The initialization happens just before the method but I am redirecting it to a new page. So I dont think it will come back and reset it.

Comment: So use $rootScope.vendorCartList instead of $scope as another case alternative